# run airflow dag for previous dates

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-2.x

I have an Airflow DAG where I run API queries based on the current date (using Python's date.today() function).

```
with DAG(
        'load_api_date',
        description='test',
        default_args=args,
        start_date=datetime(year=2023, month=4, day=17),
        schedule_interval=None,

) as dag:
....
.....
....

    def get_data(**kwargs):

        delta_date = str(date.today() - timedelta(days=2))
        params = {"aggregation": "DAY", "date": delta_date, "returntype": "csv"}
        file_date = delta_date.replace('-', '')
....
```

When this runs, the `delta_date` will always consider the current date only. Is it possible to modify the dag or pass any optional date parameters such that if needed, the DAG can also run for past dates? Or pretend that the current date is something else.

For example, if I run this today, the date.today() will be **21-04-2023**. But can I make my dag **pretend that the date.today()** is let's say **18-04-23**.

Does the "start_date" in the DAG initialisation play a part here?

Comment: I have a few questions to clarify: 1) Does the `schedule_interval` have to be `None` (so the DAG can only be externally triggered)? If the answer is yes, how is the DAG going to be triggered? 2) Are you trying to say something like _"hey, Airflow: you are supposed to run this DAG every 10 minutes starting on 2023-04-18, and if you don't have all the intended runs, try to run them and catch up to 'now' as soon as possible"_ 3) Is that `get_data` function a task?

Answer (score 0):

Your description of the problem is not so clear as:

1. There is no DAG scheduled interval
2. The DAG was created a few days ago
3. I am not sure if get_data() is a task?
4. Do you want to re-run the dag, because the state failed, does state come into the equation?

Here are a few options for you to explore, if you have any further observations or refinements, respond and I can be more prescriptive:

**Option 1 - Trigger your DAG via a CLI**

```
airflow trigger_dag load_api_date --conf '{"execution_date": "2023-04-18T00:00:00+00:00"}'
```

I believe the syntax has changed in later versions [so refer to the docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/dag-run.html#using-cli)

```
airflow dags trigger load_api_date --conf '{"date_state": "2023-04-18"}'
```

**Option 2- Use a custom date field stored as an XCOM**

You can modify your get_data function, to do the following:

1. read the XCOM variable
2. if it does not exist use your default date
3. ensure there is no human error with a date inputted for example if the date is earlier than your dag start date

```
def get_data(**kwargs):
    # Read the date value from XCom
    default_date = str(date.today() - timedelta(days=2))
    date_state = kwargs['ti'].xcom_pull(key='date_state', default=default_date)

    # Parse the date string into a datetime object
    date_obj = datetime.strptime(date_state, '%Y-%m-%d')

    # Check if the date is not less than the DAG start_date
    if date_obj.date() < kwargs['dag'].start_date.date():
        raise ValueError(f"The date value in XCom ({date_obj.date()}) is less than the DAG start_date ({kwargs['dag'].start_date.date()})")

    # Subtract 2 days from the date object to get the delta_date
    delta_date = str((date_obj - timedelta(days=2)).date())

    # Use the delta_date if the XCom value is not available
    if delta_date is None:
        delta_date = default_date

    # Use the delta_date value to build the params dictionary
    params = {"aggregation": "DAY", "date": delta_date, "returntype": "csv"}
    file_date = delta_date.replace('-', '')
```

If you are new to Airflow and need information about XCOMs [here are the docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/xcoms.html)

**Option 3 - Modify your DAG structure, to include a BranchOperator to control the flow of what tasks get executed.**

Here is a high-level overview

- We create a new function to check the date, this is used to fan out which version of the get_data function to execute, we still use XCOM to control the date, if you need to trigger it with an older date/state manually.

```
   def check_date_state(**kwargs):
        date_state = kwargs['ti'].xcom_pull(key='date_state')
        if date_state and date_state < kwargs['dag'].start_date:
            raise ValueError(f"date_state cannot be less than DAG start_date ({kwargs['dag'].start_date})")

        if date_state:
            return 'get_data_with_date_state'
        else:
            return 'get_data_without_date_state'

    get_data_without_date_state = PythonOperator(
        task_id='get_data_without_date_state',
        python_callable=get_data,
        provide_context=True,
        dag=dag,
    )

    get_data_with_date_state = PythonOperator(
        task_id='get_data_with_date_state',
        python_callable=get_data,
        provide_context=True,
        dag=dag,
    )

    check_date = BranchPythonOperator(
        task_id='check_date_state',
        python_callable=check_date_state,
        provide_context=True,
        dag=dag,
    )

    check_date >> get_data_without_date_state
    check_date >> get_data_with_date_state
```